# Getting Azure SignalR Service is not connected yet, please try again later. in local environment

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

I've been getting above error since yesterday when I'm debugging my MVC webapp locally via VS 2019. The error comes from the negotiate request which is something like below:

http://localhost:53652/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=x

I've deployed it to one of our Dev servers in Azure cloud, and now that too getting the same error and SignalR is not workable. However, SignalR is still working fine in our Production servers.

I've followed this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/909

And this: [https://forums.asp.net/t/2154631.aspx?Error+500+using+Azure+SignalR+service](https://forums.asp.net/t/2154631.aspx?Error%20500%20using%20Azure%20SignalR%20service)

But still no use.
After enabling diagnostics as per the first link, I was getting an error saying that I cannot connect to our Azure SignalR instance. But I don't get it since, the production servers can connect and working fine.

I was in Azure SignalR v1.2.3, and later updated to v1.4.3 thinking that would resolve. But still no luck.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Please add some code for your backend application, I mean the signalr startup configuration and your dev-appsettings.

Comment: This was an issue from Azure end, and they have fixed it.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/909#issuecomment-632441547